# Hide Item List Tracking item if closed

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to be able to hide any items in my list which is in the status of closed. Is this possible?

[image: Current List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit your current view and apply the filter.

Choose *Show items when the following is true*,

Then select your column (**Status**) and select condition as "*is not equals to*"

and Add value **Closed** to the last text box 
 [image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. It seems like it doesn't save the view though. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't save the view? Do you see some error while saving?

Comment: Hello, No there is no error it just doesn't save the list view when going back to the main list.